# Nextjs throws Invalid React hooks Error on next dev

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

```
MacOS BigSur
Node 14.15.3
React - 17.0.1
Rect Dom - 17.0.1
Next - 10.0.6
```

**Folder Structure**

```
/node_modules
package.json
  /app
    app.js     
    /src
      /next
        .next
        /pages
          index.jsx
....
```

**code to start server from app.js**

```
        nextServer = next({
                dev: isDev,
                dir: 'app/src/next',
            }),
        handle = nextServer.getRequestHandler();
```

When starting server using `node app/app.js`, the page is loading just fine.

But when I run `next dev app/src/next` or `next build app/src/next`.
I'm getting Invalid Hooks call error.
https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=321

Comment: From where that code came from? Is it a example from next? If it is your on code we problaby going to need more info about, as this error can mean more then one thing and can happen in more then one place in the code. But there is 2 things you could do check that you dont have two versions of react instaled and check that react and react-dom has the same version.

Comment: @WilliamRizzi The couple of lines of code is straight-up from  the nextJS documentation. I put react, and reactDOM as externals in the webpack config for the fix

Answer (score 0):

I think it was because of two versions of react in the project. I excluded react from the bundle by adding it as external in `next.config.js`.

```
    module.exports = {
      webpack: config => {
        config.externals = {
          react: 'react',
          reactDOM: 'react-dom'
        }
      
        return config;
      },
    };
```

Run `npm ls react` to see which versions of react you are using.

I think this thread might help others narrow down their issue, if some else gets stuck here.
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/9022

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps someone
In my case, the error occurred when I used the external section in my config.
So I thought maybe when I add it I am overwriting some of the default config values.
So I added ...config.externals to my object and voila, everything works fine, including the build

```
config.externals = [
  ...config.externals,
  {
    sqlite3: 'commonjs sqlite3'
  },
]
```